# How to prove that the following sequence converges?

Tags: cauchy-sequences

Let $u_1$=2 and $u_{n+1}=2+\frac{1}{u_n}$ for $n\geq 1$. Prove that the sequence converges to $\sqrt{2} +1$.

I have no clue how to do it,probably using Cauchy sequence definition. The hint given in textbook is: $|u_{n+2}-u_{n+1}|<\frac{1}{4}|u_{n+1}-u_n|$

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for $n>1$,
$u_n > 2$
so $u_n < 5/2$
so it is bounded.

Then

$u_{n+2}-u_{n+1}
=(2+1/u_{n+1})-(2+1/u_{n})
=1/u_{n+1})-1/u_{n}
=(u_n-u_{n+1})/(u_nu_{n+1})
$

and

$u_nu_{n+1} > 4$.

Take absolute values to get the result.

The standard next step is to iterate this to get

$|u_{n+k+1}-u_{n+k}| < |u_{n+1}-u_n|/4^k$

and then use the triangle inequality
to show that
$|u_{n+k}-u_n| \to 0$
as $n \to \infty$
for all $k$.

This works for

$|u_{n+2}-u_{n+1}| < |u_{n+1}-u_{n}|/(1+c)$

for any $c>0$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!